# Имена пользователей vk.com на кириллице

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, vkontakte-api

Как получать имена пользователей vk на кириллице? код ниже возвращает имена транслитом.

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[params setObject:searchText forKey:@"q"];
[params setObject:@"sex, photo_50" forKey:@"fields"];
[params setObject:@"friends" forKey:@"from_list"];
[params setObject:@"ru" forKey:@"lang"];

__block VKRequest *callingRequest = [[VKApi users] search:params];
callingRequest.debugTiming = YES;
callingRequest.requestTimeout = 10;

[callingRequest executeWithResultBlock: ^(VKResponse *response) {
    arrFoundUsers = [response.json objectForKey:@"items"];
    [_tblFoundUsers reloadData];
    callingRequest = nil;
} errorBlock: ^(NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error: %@", error]);
    callingRequest = nil;
}];
```

Comment: Вы вызываете метод `users.search`? Вроде все возвращает как надо, судя по запросам которые можно организовать тут `http://vk.com/dev/users.search` Может это непосредственно пользователь себя так назвал транслитом? Такое тоже бывает

Comment: имена всех пользователей возвращаются в транслите

Comment: да users.search

Comment: Неправда. Введите слово "привет" или "маша" и пр. Все возвращается нормально. Может вы где-то принудительно конвертите как раз в транслит. Скорее всего у вас в настройках ВК стоит английский язык. Вот вам и транслит приходит. Или как-то параметр `lang` вы передаете со значением `en`, вместо `ru`

Comment: http://vk.com/dev/users.search тут все нормально работает, не вопрос. А мой код возвращает транслит

Comment: Сможете написать тут свой запрос, в том виде как он у вас отсылается? Не код, а именно конечный результат (что-то типа `https://api.vk.com/method/execute?code=return API.users.search({count:30,fields:"photo,online,screen_name,sex,can_write_private_message,verified",v:5.8});&https=1&callback=Site.APIRequestCallbacks[182]&access_token=11111111111111111111111&v=4.99&lang=ru`) ?. Со всеми HTTP заголовками

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всем спасибо. Вот решение:

```
callingRequest.preferredLang = @"ru";
```

Answer (score 0):

Пара версий:

1. настройка языка системы на вашем устройстве. *Может быть*, при выполнении запросов автоматически добавляется HTTP-заголовок предпочтительных локалей `Accept-Language: ru,en-us` – ВК API его принимает к сведению и от этого зависит язык имён.
2. [параметр `lang`](https://vk.com/dev/api_requests) при выполнении любых запросов к api можно явно задать, и тогда точно должно возвращаться в кириллице.

Comment: Так он в запросе вон вроде и отправляет `lang` = `ru`. Однако ничего